# в JS заполнение двумерного массива вводимыми числами

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки, преобразование

Вводятся число n, а затем элементы матрицы n на n.
Нужно вывести все числа, больше или равные среднему арифметическому матрицы.
Каждое число выводить с новой строки.
Числа выводить в порядке обхода матрицы слева направо, сверху вниз.
Пример: n=3
Input - 3 7 5 1 5 9 0 7 8
output -
7
5
5
9
7
8
Не получается заполнить двумерный массив, запутался...
Вот часть кода:

```js
 let n=parseInt(prompt())
let arr=new Array(n)
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr[i] = [];     
    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        arr[j].push(prompt().split(' '))
    }
}
```

пробовал так:

```js
 let n=parseInt(prompt())
    let arr=[]
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = [];     
        for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            arr.push(parseInt(prompt()))
        }
    }
```

Тоже ошибка

Comment: И что? Что от нас то требуется? Мы ДЗ здесь за вас не делаем. Можем посоветовать что-то, только объясните подробнее, что вы делали и что у вас не получается.

Comment: "запутался" --- это не чёткое описание проблемы

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первом варианте `.split(' '`) - лишний, во 2м все-таки `arr[i]` раз уж матрица. Ну и не забывать приводить к числу prompt.

```js
let n = +prompt('Введите размер матрицы');
let arr = new Array(n);
let sum = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr[i] = [];     
    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      let value = +prompt('Введите число');
      sum += value;
      arr[i].push(value)
    }
}
let average = sum/(Math.pow(n,2));
console.log(arr.flat(), average, n);

for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j<n; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] >= average) {
           console.log(arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

// Вариант последнего куска для ленивых
/*
arr.flat(2)
  .forEach(el => {
    if (el >= average) console.log(el)
  });
*/
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: Вот это `parseInt(+prompt('Введите размер матрицы'))` и это `new Array(n)` кажется избыточным. В первом случае вы 2 раза к числу приводите, во втором, создаете пустые элементы и далее их инициализируете. Видится, что обычный arr.push([]) в цикле выглядит логичнее